# Ionic DateTime component not displaying day name on pick time

Tags: datetime, ionic-framework

I'm developing `Hybrid` app using `ionic framework`. I want to display day name during ionic `date-time` pick time. I can see day name after pick date but i can't see it on picktime. I have used below code.

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="DDD,YYYY MMM DD" pickerFormat="DDD,YYYY MMM DD" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
```

**This is what I get:**

[image]

**This is what I am expecting:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ionic added the DDD and DDDD in the pickerFormat. I have no idea why. This code is in the ion-datetime template as looking into /node_modules/date-format/ , there is no such format is handled for the same.

Best will be to use an external module, like [Angular Material datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) or make your own select with array of the days.